# I have product_id inside line_items array in order table, I want to show product name against this product_id in laravel using vue.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, laravel, vue.js

I have a cell called line_items in orders table. Inside line_items there are data like

```
  [
      {"customer_id":"30","product_id":"10","unit_id":"2","quantity":"1","price":"2700","total_price":"2700"},
      {"customer_id":"30","product_id":"43","unit_id":"1","quantity":"5","price":"7","total_price":"35"}
    ]
```

I have products table where product's name is stored in a cell called name. The id of products table are the product_id in the above data.

Now I have a route like

```
 Route::get('json/{order}', 'ReturnController@json')->name('json');
```

This is the json function in ReturnController

```
 public function json(Order $order)
    {
        return response()->json([ 'orders' => $order ]);
    }
```

This is the json output in http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/7 route

```
{"order":{"id":7,"company_id":1,"order_type":1,"order_no":"12","date":"2019-01-16","status":"1","transaction_raw":[{"amount":"82264","transaction_type":3,"payment_type":1,"owner_type":"App\\Model\\Customer","owner_id":"1"},{"amount":"0","transaction_type":4,"payment_type":1,"owner_type":"App\\Model\\Customer","owner_id":"1","account_head_id":1}],"line_items":[{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"10","unit_id":"2","quantity":"5","price":"2700","total_price":"13500"},{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"43","unit_id":"1","quantity":"52","price":"7","total_price":"364"},{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"9","unit_id":"2","quantity":"18","price":"3800","total_price":"68400"}],"total":82264,"discount":0,"sub_total":82264,"paid":0,"due":82264,"supplier_id":0,"customer_id":1,"others_fin":"{\"transport\":\"0\",\"type\":\"income\"}","created_at":"2019-01-16 19:13:27","updated_at":"2019-01-16 19:13:27"}}
```

This is code in vue

```
 <tr v-for="order in orders.line_items">
     <td><input name="" v-model="order.product_id"></td>
     <td><input name="" v-model="PODUCT NAME"></td>
     <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity"></td>
     <td><input name="" v-model="order.price" disabled></td>
     <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity * order.price"></td>
 </tr>
```

I want to show product name from product table where is written PRODUCT NAME. How to do it.

I have both Product and Order models.

Answer (score 0):

Try to eager load the relation:

```
return response()->json([ 'orders' => $order->load('product') ]);
```

After that (assuming the order belongs to a product), you can show the product name in Vue like this:

```
{{ order.product.name }}
```

Comment: These are the codes I have added in Order model, but yet the expected result is not getting.

public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

Comment: It's not working, please help me. Getting this error in console. 

_TypeError: "order.product is undefined"_

Comment: First check if the json route `/json/7` contains the product.

Comment: No, there is no product in json route !